# C++: QGridLayout - Whitespace between widgets

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have a problem with a QGridLayout.

[image]

Each square is a widget and I have a loop like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++;)
{
   ui->layout->addWidget(new Square(this),rowNr,colNr);
}
```

The QGridLayout is part of a QFrame.

My question is: Why is there so much whitespace between each square (horizontally)

This is the code for a square

```
QPainter painter(this);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
painter.setBrush(QBrush("#c56c00"));
painter.drawRect(0, 0, 30, 30);
```

Where is my problem? I want to have each cell 1 by 1 without any space between them. I dont know why it is vertically correct.. Im completely new to C++ and Qt..

Comment: The `QGridLayout` automatically divides the space of its parent layout to correctly cover it with cells. Consult the [reference](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html) for properties and methods to alter such spacing. Let me know if it helped.

Comment: You need to have that empty space somewhere. Where? Just right and bottom? Or on all sides equally? In any case, you need to add spacers which have size policy Expanding. If you want to center this, I would create 3x3 QGridLayout, where your current layout would be inserted in the middle, and then add 4 empty QWidgets with appropriate size policy above, below, left and right.

Comment: I just want to have each square with like 1px distance to all sides. Kinda lika a chess board. But not a fixed one (e.g 10x10 fields), it should be variable like 5x5 or 25x25 etc. How could I do that. The QT doc. really confuses me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPushButton>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
        : QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        resize(800, 800);

        auto widget = new QWidget(this);
        setCentralWidget(widget);

        auto gl = new QGridLayout(widget);
        gl->setSpacing(0);
        gl->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignLeft);
        widget->setLayout(gl);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            gl->addWidget(new QPushButton(QString::number(i*10 + j), this), i, j);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have fixed size widgets (30x30), each widget is exactly 30x30 pixels. If your layout is larger horizontally/vertically, the spacing is increased to allow even distribution.

**Example:**
Let's say you have a frame with a width of 100px with 3 squares aligned horizontally. 3 times 30 equals 90 so you have 10px remaining. Since layouts in general try to evenly distribute the components that they align you will get approx. 3px spacing between each square.

You either have to play with the sizing of your `QFrame` (my guess is that it is not fixed size and increases/decreases in size when you resize it) or avoid using fixed size widgets inside it.

In general I would recommend either sticking with fixed size for all of your components or make the children (here: squares) to properly resize.

PS: For the task at hand it's quite easy to provide a minimal working example. ;)

Comment: Alright I got your point. So the QGridLayout automatically fills the whole space of its parent (in my case: the frame)?  My task is to achieve that dynamically so that the user can change the amount of squares shown. Its like a game with 10x10 fields, or 20x20 etc. - So a fixed size is my solution? How can I achieve that? The Doc. from Qt kinda confuses me

Comment: If you just want squares why not make them resizable? Since it's a widget you can use the size policy to take as much space as possible. Do this for all squares and your grid will be filled without any empty space in between.